# Twilio AutoPilot Redirect to webhook Error - 90100

Tags: redirect, twilio, webhooks, twilio-programmable-chat

I've bluid a bot in Twilio AutoPilot and once my bot collected all the information, I need it run a redirect to a webhook.

This webhook works outgoing (I do receive the collected information on the end point) however I'm getting an 90100 error.

This is my code for the webhook:

[Code of webhook in Twilio Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzR0c.png)

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const response = {
    actions: [
      {
        "say": "ik heb denk ik een call naar Zapier gemaakt."
      },
      {
            "redirect": {
        "uri": "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxxxx/oxp6a20/?client=" + event.UserIdentifier + "&materiaal=" + event.Field_materiaal_Value.toLowerCase(),
        "method": "POST"
      }
          }
    ]
  }
  callback(null, response);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is the direct URL returning JSON as described here - Redirecting to URLs
When redirecting to a URL, Redirect will make an HTTP callback to your application and will expect an Autopilot Actions JSON as a response.- https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect.

Comment: Thanks @Alan. This could be the case! The response from zapier is quite simple and I believe i can't edit it.

Comment: I wonder if the Handoff action would be better? https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/hand-off

Comment: @alan gave that a try but Handoff only works with voice. We're developing for WhatsApp

Comment: Yes it looks like Zapier is quite restrictive here, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467286/zapier-modification-of-webhook-listener-http-response). Have you considered creating another Twilio Function where you do the `POST` to Zapier (see [Twilio doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-json)) and then return an Autopilot Actions JSON and you call this in your `redirect`?

Comment: To extend what @yvesonline wrote, there are a number of calling 3rd party API code examples here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart. In particular, look at the example, Make a Read Request to an External API.